# How to implement color gradients in the google maps Swift API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

i want to display data points (Google Maps Swift) with different intensities from green to red. The area of the data points on the map should stay the same.
the GMUWeightedLatLng class takes the coordinates as an argument as well as the intensity.
The latter, however, is representing the area of that particular point, it does not change the color.

```
let coords = GMUWeightedLatLng(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude), intensity: 1)

heatmapLayer.weightedData.append(coords)
```

heatmapLayer.gradient provides the possibility to change the gradient, but it makes it the same for all data points, whereas I want each point to exhibit customized shades from green to red, with the same area.

```
let gradientColors: [UIColor] = [.green, .red]
heatmapLayer.gradient = GMUGradient(
            colors: gradientColors,
            startPoints: gradientStartPoints,
            colorMapSize: 256)
```

I would very much appreciate any help!